# Design: App or View for different Business Roles?

Tags: lightning-apps, permissions, roles, design

I am new to Salesforce and have a design question.

I have very different types of users that will be interacting with Salesforce - some will want to see very different types of information than others. I have been modelling this in terms of Apps: One for a sales person, one for a person who deals with Donations, etc. Each app has different tabs relevant to that role.

This works just fine, but I have the nagging feeling that Salesforce isn't meant to be used this way and that I should be managing this through roles or permissions, or something like that. Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Salesforce role based access is quite complex to start with - you are correct in thinking that it will need to be based on a mixture of Roles, Permissions and the Apps available to the users.

Comment: All apps are are a set of quick access tabs. Even if they do it have access to an app they could still access the tab. Think of it like the FM1-5 presets on your radio. Do use apps thinking it restricts access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider both [Field-Level Security](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=0) and [Sharing Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_about_sharing_rules.htm).

I would recommend go over the [Data Security](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/data_security) Trailhead module to learn all about salesforce security features.